# Python Tkinter Text автодополнение

Tags: python, tkinter

Я планирую создать небольшой проект в котором при вводе буквы сбоку появляется tooltip при нажатии на которую (или на горячую клавишу) слово автоматически дополняется. База слов есть.
Это должно выглядеть примерно как на картинке.

[image: яндекс почта].

Начало стандартное

```
def autoc():
    pass
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
text = Text().pack(expand=1,fill="both")
window.bind("<Key>", autoc)
window.mainloop()
```

Но функция... Перебирания всего списка слов (примерно 7 млн) будет сильно тормозить программу. Слова лежат в .json файле. Нет ли способа как то не нагружая программу всё это сделать?

Comment: Похожий код, который используется в ответе web developer, есть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71816574/autocomplete-with-backspacing-tkinter, можете связаться с автором может он поможет пройти часть препятствий.